# Как сохранить скачанный файл в оприделенную директорию? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, download

Нашёл вот такой код:

```
import urllib.request
logo = urllib.request.urlopen("https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1gkTOtZ7K72IxxTQ8W1bHMmLglvAYUfIe&export=download").read()
f = open("photo.jpg", "wb")
f.write(logo)
f.close()
```

Но проблема в том что при скачивании файл сохраняется на диск **С** и я не знаю, как задать директорию, куда бы сохранялся файл.

Comment: `f = open("D:\\Папка\\Подпапка\\photo.jpg", "wb")`  А так-же релативные пути `..\\anotherdir\\filename.jpg`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1357292

Answer (score 1):

Просто указываете в `open` полный путь. Например так:

```
f = open("D:\\images\\photo.jpg", "wb")
```